# running a command repeatedly on a remote server

Tags: powershell

I wrote the following script to run a command on a remote server with 5 sec interval. The command inside $LogrCmd variable runs on a remote server to check if a particular service is up or down. I expect the script to poll the service every 5 seconds until the service is completely down. However the scripts exits out immediately even if the service is up.

```
$LogrCmd = get-content 'c:\temp\info.cfg' | select-string -Pattern cheetahdev
      while (-not (Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {& cmd.exe /c "$LogrCmd"})) {
 ## Wait a specific interval
       Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
                       }
```

Here's the contents of the info.cfg file which runs against the remote host.

"C:\PWX\pwxcmd displaystatus -sv cheetahdev"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would do better to use a `do / while` loop here instead of a `while` loop:

```
$LogrCmd = Get-Content 'c:\temp\info.cfg' | Select-String -Pattern cheetahdev
do {
  cmd.exe /c "$LogrCmd"

  ## Wait a specific interval
  Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
} while ( $LASTEXITCODE -eq 0 )
```

This will always run the command once, sleep, then check to see if the command succeeded. If the command succeeded it will continue the loop. Of course, you can tailor the `while` condition to check for other exit codes and conditions as well.

Note that for external commands it's best to rely on `$LASTEXITCODE` most of the time to check for command success, unless you need to parse the output of the command or something else less common.

Also note that by reading the full command from the file like that opens you up to code injection attacks by someone familiar with how to manipulate your `info.cfg`.

Comment: Thank you. I changed the code as you suggested and it worked. Do you have any suggestions on handling the input commands in a better way.